# CouchDB sort by date string

Tags: couchdb

I want to use the _find API of CouchDB and the result should be sorted by a specific field which is not part of the selector. I created an index via the API which is working fine for most of the fields. Except the date string field. I already found this [Example](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#sorting-by-dates) how to sort on date fields. But for me it is not clear how the design document needs to look like.

Field example:  `"downloadedTimestamp": "2023-07-11T11:31:58.803Z"`

My current design docs for sorting text fields look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/group-sort-index",
  "_rev": "1-a38ed6a43ed163da86849bb422d7a499",
  "language": "query",
  "views": {
    "group-sort-index": {
      "map": {
        "fields": {
          "group": "asc"
        },
        "partial_filter_selector": {}
      },
      "options": {
        "def": {
          "fields": [
            "group"
          ]
        }
      },
      "reduce": "_count"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want query by fields `a`, `b` and additionally sort by `c`, then you would index fields `a`, `b` and `c` and at query time do a `_find` whose `selector` was for known values of `a` and `b`, sorting by `a`, `b` & `c` e.g.

```js
{
  "selector": {
    "a": "firstvalue",
    "b": "secondvalue",
  },
  "sort": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
}
```

Fortunately, timestamps of the form `2023-07-11T11:31:58.803Z` sort in date/time order as the most significant items are to the left.